# Jetbrains ContractAnnotations interface or implementation

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper, jetbrains-ide

While using the Jetbrains [`ContractAnnotation`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/15/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/) I was wondering whether or not to put them on the interface method, the implementation method or both.
e.g. (simple example)

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    [ContractAnnotation("=> notnull")]
    MyClass MakeInstance();
}

public class MyFactory : MyInterface
{
    [ContractAnnotation("=> notnull")] // Is this needed here, too?
    MyClass MakeInstance()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

It seems to me that putting the `ContractAnnotation` on both the interface and the implementation is a bit redundant, but the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Contract_Annotations.html) does not mention where to put them.

I found out that `ContractAnnotation`s can be inherited, but I don't know whether that means the ReSharper's Code Analysis can also work with inherited contracts.

---

Can someone maybe shed some light on whether it is needed to put this annotation in both the interface and implementation?

Where does it make the most sense, if it is not needed in both places?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/15/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/ talks about the impact of adding the attribute (i.e. it shows how Resharper will give extra feedback). Given that, my suggestion would be to try adding it to the interface first. Does it give you the feedback? If not, try adding it just to the class. If not, try adding it to both. _In practical terms, you should add it to both - especially in codebases where DI/IOC is involved._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a more detailed test and found out that `ContractAnnotation`s are infact inherited and the code analysis actually considers inherited contracts.

---

```
public class Class
{
    public bool Get() => true;
}

public interface IFactory
{
    [ContractAnnotation("=> notnull")]
    Class GetInstance();
}

public class Factory : IFactory
{
    // No redundant ContractAnnotation needed here.
    public Class GetInstance()
    {
        return new Class();
    }
}

public class DemoHost
{
    public void Run()
    {
        IFactory ifactory = new Factory();
        ifactory.GetInstance().Get(); // No null warning here.

        Factory factory = new Factory();
        factory.GetInstance().Get(); // No null warning here as well: obviously the annotation must have been inherited.
    }
}
```